# Move specific files into backup directory keeping folder structure

Tags: find, mv

I have Original Source and Backup destination. Inside Original folder I have a lot of files types. I only need JPG, LOG and TXT. I already did the Directory Structure Copy with this command:

```
cd /var/Sys012/Logs && find . -type d -exec mkdir -p -- /home/re-born/Backup/Logs/{} \;`
```

How to find `*.TXT`, `*.LOG` and `*.JPG` and move into respective Backup Folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync`:

```
rsync -av -m \
  --include="*/" \
  --include="*.jpg" \
  --include="*.log" \
  --include="*.txt" \
  --exclude="*" \
"/var/Sys012/Logs" "/home/re-born/Backup/"
```

`-m` lets `rsync` avoid to create empty folders. Omit this option if you don't want this.

This will also create the directory structure for you.
To include the extensions independent from case, you might need `--include="*.[jJ][pP][gG]"`.

Comment: Thank you pLumo, I made a mistake formulating the question, the problem here is the mandatory file is the JPG for example, I have 300.JPG and need to copy 300.log and 300.txt, next I have 301.M4V and 301.TXT and 301.LOG, those files I wont be copied, lets say I need to copy the *.jpg but there childs are *.txt and *.log avoid to copy the *.txt and *.log from other extensions like m4v, png and so... thanks in advance